# where to put css and javascript files in eclipse dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, dynamic, web, project

I decided to add an external css file for a dynamic web project created in eclipse. If I create "fooStyle.css" and refer to it within a jsp file where should I put the css file in the project folder?

```
<html>
    <head><title>Foo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fooStyle.css">
    </head>
     <body>....</body>
</html>
```

[update]

The below link gives me some idea where to put. It says I should put it under theme, but I am not sure this is a directory I have to create manually under WebContent or at the same level as of WebContent.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html

Comment: WebContent is the directory for... the web content. If you put something outside of this directory, it won't be availaible in the generated web app.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thanks! I will put it under WebContent and check the behavior of the page.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Yep, it worked just fine. As I put "fooStyle.css" right under WebContent folder and the jsp file picked it up just fine via <link rel="stylesheet" href="fooStyle.css"> html tag.